# Why does arr[1] print what appears to be arr[0]?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

*The program below is from 'The C Answer Book', Exercise 1-13. This is for comprehension & self-study.*

---

*I set the stage for my question below:*

---

```
#define MAXWORD 11
```

---

Elements of array wl[ ] are initialized to zero.

```
/* INITIALIZE WORD LENGTH COUNTER */
for (i = 0; i < MAXWORD; ++i) {
    wl[i] = 0;
}
```

If word sizes are greater than zero and less than the maximum, store them in the array.

```
if (nc > 0) {
    /* INCREMENT WORD LENGTH COUNTER */
    if (nc < MAXWORD) {
        ++wl[nc];
    }
    ...
}
```

**The loop below starts with i = 1. Why does wl[1] print what appears to be wl[0]?**

```
/* PRINT COUNTER HEADER */
for (i = i; i < MAXWORD; ++i) {
    printf("%5d - %5d : ", i, wl[i]);
    ...
}
```

---

**¡EXTRA CREDIT!**

**Please teach me how I could have found your answer by myself.**

---

Output when i = 0

```
 0 -     0 : 
 1 -   111 : ************
 2 -   129 : ***************
 3 -    31 : ***
 4 -    42 : ****
 5 -    32 : ***
 6 -    24 : **
 7 -    24 : **
 8 -    13 : *
 9 -    17 : *
10 -     6 : *
There are 9 words >= 11
```

---

Output when i = 1

```
 1 -   111 : ************
 2 -   129 : ***************
 3 -    31 : ***
 4 -    42 : ****
 5 -    32 : ***
 6 -    24 : **
 7 -    24 : **
 8 -    13 : *
 9 -    17 : *
10 -     6 : *
There are 9 words >= 11
```

---

COMPLETE SOURCE CODE:

```
/* Write a program to print a histogram of the lengths of words in
 * its input. It is easy to draw the histogram with the bars horizontal; a vertical
 * orientation is more challenging. 
 *
 *  1   |   ***
 *  2   |   ****
 *  3   |   ******
 *  4   |   *********
 *  5   |   **
 *  X   |   **********
 *  
 *  There were 7 words greater than 11 character.
 *  --------------------------------------------- */

#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXHIST 15                                  /* max length of histogram */
#define MAXWORD 11                                  /* max length of a word */
#define IN      1                                   /* inside a word */
#define OUT     0                                   /* outside a word */

/* print horizontal histogram */
int
main(void)
{
    int c, i, nc, state;
    int len;                                        /* length of each bar */
    int maxvalue;                                   /* maximum value for wl[] */
    int ovflow;                                     /* number of overflow words */
    int wl[MAXWORD];                                /* word length counters */

    state = OUT;
    nc = 0;                                         /* number of chars in a word */
    ovflow = 0;                                     /* number of overflow words */
    /* INITIALIZE WORD LENGTH COUNTER */
    for (i = 0; i < MAXWORD; ++i) {
        wl[i] = 0;
    }
    /* READ CHARACTERS UNTIL EOF */
    while ( (c = getchar() ) != EOF) {
        /* IF BLANK FOUND */
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t') {
            state = OUT;
            /* IF WORD FOUND */
            if (nc > 0) {
                /* INCREMENT WORD LENGTH COUNTER */
                if (nc < MAXWORD) {
                    ++wl[nc];
                }
                /* INCREMENT OVERFLOW COUNTER */
                else {
                    ++ovflow;
                }
            }
            nc = 0;
        }
        /* NEW WORD FOUND */
        else if (state == OUT) {
            state = IN;
            nc = 1;                                 /* beginning of a new word */
        }
        /* SAME WORD FOUND */
        else {
            ++nc;                                   /* inside a word */
        }
    }
    maxvalue = 0;
    /* FIND LARGEST WORD */
    for (i = 1; i < MAXWORD; ++i) {
        if (wl[i] > maxvalue) {
            maxvalue = wl[i];
        }
    }
    /* PRINT COUNTER HEADER */
    for (i = 1; i < MAXWORD; ++i) {
        printf("%5d - %5d : ", i, wl[i]);
        /* FIND A COUNTER */
        if (wl[i] > 0) {
            /* SCALE ITS HISTOGRAM */
            if ( (len = wl[i] * MAXHIST / maxvalue) <= 0) {
                len = 1;
            }
        }
        /* NO COUNTER FOUND */
        else {
            len = 0;
        }
        /* PRINT COUNTER LENGTH */
        while (len > 0) {
            putchar('*');
            --len;
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    /* PRINT OVERFLOW COUNT */
    if (ovflow > 0) {
        printf("There are %d words >= %d\n", ovflow, MAXWORD);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `#define MAXWORD = 11`?? You probably meant `#define MAXWORD 11`.

Comment: "The loop below starts with i = 1", but: `for (i = i; i < MAXWORD; ++i) {...}` seems to be wrong because of the `i = i`.

Comment: @devnull - That's a typo in my question. In the actual code it's written correctly as you point out.

Comment: Then FIX it in your question.

Comment: The output you're giving us looks correct to me. What problem are you having?

Comment: @Nabla Ok, it's fine. I didn't check the whole code.

Comment: @pzaenger for (i = i; i < MAXWORD; ++i) {...} is how it's coded in 'The C Answer Book' and it appears to be the version which is correct given that when i = 0, the expected value is not printed. The expected value would be 111, but 0 is printed.

Comment: @nabla I've corrected my typo.

Comment: @NikosC. I've fixed it in the question.

Comment: @NikosC. Why is the first element of the array zero when zero should not be stored in the array? The array holds MAXWORD elements (11). The eleventh element should be a '\0' right? That leaves an array of 0-9. if (nc > 0) should not store a 0 in wl[0], the value 111 should be in wl[0]. Make sense?

Comment: instead of `c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t'`   use `isspace()`

Comment: @Nabla I did it again. Must have not clicked 'save'. Thanks.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I'm using only techniques I've read up to now in K&R 2E, as is the author of 'The C Answer Book', so your suggestion, though good, isn't relevant here.

Comment: @user3193230 `wl` is an array of `int`, not of `char`. There is no `\0` in there. Also `wl[0]` is zero, because it never is used in the code, besides at initialization. The reason being probably, that no input string has length 0. (So why count those?) The first element of `wl` seems to be wasted on purpose to make indexing more natural.

Comment: @Nabla I believe you're correct! Ha! I've been racking my brain about this for days. Tondo & Gimpel need to comment their code! Thanks! Write up an answer and I'll vote it up. Gonna test it more to understand it better hands-on. Thanks so much. :)

Comment: @user3193230 No, if you start at `i=1`, you are not printing the first element `wl[0]`. If you start at `i=0`, then you are also printing `wl[0]`, which is always `0` by design of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is working well: `wl` stores a count of the words with length equal to or less than 10 (`wl[1]` the number of words of length 1, `wl[2]` the number of words of length 2, etc), so `wl[0]` is always 0 because no words of length 0 exist.

Sometimes when you work with arrays you want to forget that the positions of the arrays going from 0 to n-1 and simplify other parts of the code, and it is what is happening here.

This is how it will be working with index 0

```
#define MAXWORD 10                                  /* max length of a word */

...

int wl[MAXWORD];                                /* word length counters */  

/* INITIALIZE WORD LENGTH COUNTER */
for (i = 0; i < MAXWORD; ++i) {
    wl[i] = 0;
}

...


/* IF WORD FOUND */
if (nc > 0) {
    /* INCREMENT WORD LENGTH COUNTER */
    if (nc <= MAXWORD) {
        ++wl[nc - 1];
    }
    /* INCREMENT OVERFLOW COUNTER */
    else {
        ++ovflow;
    }
}

...

for (i = 0; i < MAXWORD; ++i) {
    printf("%5d - %5d : ", i+1, wl[i]);

    ...
}
```

`++wl[nc - 1];` and `printf("%5d - %5d : ", i+1, wl[i]);` as rare and dificult understand the example.
The code is ok, but i, for clarifier what i think that the author try to to do, will suggest this

```
#define MAXWORD 10                                  /* max length of a word */

...

int wl[MAXWORD + 1];                                /* word length counters */  

/* INITIALIZE WORD LENGTH COUNTER */
for (i = 1; i < MAXWORD; ++i) {
    wl[i] = 0;
}

...


/* IF WORD FOUND */
if (nc > 0) {
    /* INCREMENT WORD LENGTH COUNTER */
    if (nc <= MAXWORD) {
        ++wl[nc];
    }
    /* INCREMENT OVERFLOW COUNTER */
    else {
        ++ovflow;
    }
}

...

for (i = 1; i <= MAXWORD; ++i) {
    printf("%5d - %5d : ", i, wl[i]);

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because no words have length 0, and nothing is ever stored in `wl[0]`, see the `if(nc > 0)`.

The index is the length of the word, and the value at that index is the number of words of that length.

The number of words of length 0 in a piece of text is more like a question of philosophy, than something you can get a computer to calculate.